# How to find indexes of max n values in array

Tags: arrays, ruby

I have an array `[0, 0, 10, 0, 3, 1]`. I want to have the indexes of max three elements from this array, which would be: `[2, 4, 5]`.

How do I do it without finding max element, delete it (make 0), then find next one, delete it and at last find third one? I can't sort this array, I need index from the current position.

Comment: TiSer, sawa's answer is much better than mine. I would encourage you to mark his answer as the accepted one, rather than mine.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

```
a = [0, 0, 10, 0, 3, 1]
a.each_index.max_by(3){|i| a[i]} # => [2, 4, 5]
```

or

```
[0, 0, 10, 0, 3, 1].each_with_index.max(3).map(&:last) # => [2, 4, 5]
```

Answer (score 3):

```
arr = [1, 3, 2, 4]
n = 2
p arr.each_with_index.sort.map(&:last).last(n).reverse
#=> [3,1]
```

How does it work ?

1. `arr.each_with_index.sort`

Will return an array of arrays. Each of the arrays is constructed as follows `[value, index]` and they are sorted based on `value`. In our example it would return `[[1, 0], [2, 2], [3, 1], [4, 3]]`.

2. `arr.map(&:last)`

Will loop through all of those arrays and take the last value of the array (the index) and return an array of those indexes. In our example it will return `[0, 2, 1, 3]`. Now we have an array of indexes sorted in ascending order so the first value is the minimum and the last value is the maximum.

3. `arr.last(n)`

Returns an array containing last n values of an array. Since the array is in ascending order the max n values are the last n values.

4. `arr.reverse`

Reverts an array. It is optional. If you want to have the max in first position of your array and the Nth maximum value at the end then use reverse, else do not use it.

Comment: Ok. I like your description of each step. Thanks.